# SwiftUI NavigationBarTitle not updating

Tags: swiftui

i figure out how to change the NavTitle in SwiftUI if we update or increase an Amount.

```
class User: ObservableObject {
@Published var first = "xxxxx"
@Published var last = "yyyyyyyyyy"
@Published var totalAmount = 0
    @Published var totalpieces = 0
}
struct testTextfield: View {
    @ObservedObject var user = User()


func update() {
    user.first = "firstnametest"
    user.last = "lastname"
    user.totalAmount += 1
    user.totalpieces += 1

    print(user.totalAmount)
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form{
            VStack{
                Text("\(user.first) \(user.last)")
                TextField("first", text: $user.first)
                TextField("last", text: $user.last)

                Button(action: {
                    self.update()
                }) {
                    Text("push button")
                }
            }
        }

        .navigationBarTitle("\(user.totalpieces, specifier: "%.0f") pieces", displayMode: .inline)




      }

    }
}
```

but the print statement is correct and increases correctly but the amount in the top navbar is still 0.

is anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
.navigationBarTitle("\(self.user.totalpieces.description ) pieces", displayMode: .inline)
```

I guess this is a bug when using the specifier and using it with '_FormatSpecifiable'